# Yii return a view from routes file

Tags: php, view, yii, return, render

How to make same thing in Yii? Code in Laravel:

web.php:

```
Route::get('blog', function () {
    return view('blog.index');
});
```

All I need is to return a view by url. Where and how can I do this? I didn't find good docs for this.

Comment: if yii2 then return $this->render('view_name');

Comment: @RajeshPradhan looks like here's yii one.

Comment: **@RajeshPradhan** can you tell where I need to do this?

Comment: In controller propably.

Comment: in controller, for your action add this $this->render('view_name');

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this in your controller

```
public function actionIndex(){

   return $this->render('view_name');
}
```